# Can SqlServer 2019 store UTF-8 in VARCHAR datatype?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

We have a Large Enterprise Java Application which supports only English , Need to Enhance it to support all UTF-8 foreign language.
We have almost 150 Tables and 1400 Varchar columns with a huge 30K lines Up-gradable DDL file for Oracle and SQLServer(2 DB Supported).

For Oracle with a small DB configuration change we are able to store UTF-8 in all existing 1400 Varchar columns.No need to modify DDL file.

But for SQLServer we need to modify all VARCHAR into NVARCHAR ,And it should work for both New Client as we as existing client (UPGRADE).
This seems to be a huge task .. we already implemented t-sql code to automatically do this.

Is there any possibility with SQLServer 2019 where we can store UTF-8 directly in existing VARCHAR fields without datatype change ??

Comment: Short answer. Yes. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/introducing-utf-8-support-for-sql-server/ba-p/734928. But you need to use utf 8 collation everywhere that needs it

Comment: @MartinSmith It looks like a similar to convert into NVARCHAR where alter columnn required for setting collation

Comment: I was wrong, @HoneyBadger, and I have removed my comment.

Comment: @Chanky yes, you're going to either need to change the database collation (which isn't simple) or the columns one by one, or use `nvarchar`.

Comment: It's also worth nothing that characters that do require more than one byte will use 2 characters in the `varchar` value. Therefore, for example the character `Ð` won't fit in a `char(1)` with the collation `COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8`. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a38cb11c010246ea2159830ef3008fc9)

Comment: @Lamu Is there any way to change all old columns in new utf8 collation in SQL 2019 ? Or we need to do alter for each column which is a very tough task ?